# Gradient borders with radius solution isn't working with tailwindcss

Tags: css, tailwind-css, linear-gradients

I have seen the gradient borders with radius work on [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/) with this particular code snippet.

```
<div class="fem">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum neque debitis at ad fugit, esse sequi rem ab consequatur id sint veniam ex quam adipisci. Ab itaque officia atque id!
  </p>
</div>

.fem {
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.fem:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: -5px;
 left: -5px;
 right: -5px;
 bottom: -5px;
 width: calc(100% + 10px);
 height: calc(100% + 10px);
 z-index: -1;
 border-radius: 12px;
 background: linear-gradient(130deg,#ff7a18,#af002d 41.07%,#319197 76.05%);  
}
```

I have tested this code on [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/pumasov/1/edit?html,css,output) and it seems to be working perfectly fine.

[image]

Now, I'm working on a tailwind application and this same code isn't working for me.

I feel that some of the base styles might be causing this erratic behaviour. I can't seem to figure out how to correct it.

Here is the link to [tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/0m9nrK1LaS)

On tailwind, I'm seeing invisible gradient borders

Comment: z-index puts it all the way below the other element. You can nowdays  use background-clip : example https://play.tailwindcss.com/o1xygkhV6D?file=css so need to set average z-index and position (and mind BFC) for a pseudo and its parent.

Comment: I'm aware of this particular solution; But this has unintentional side effects on android mobile browser. It shows an extra line

Comment: then do not use a pseudo with z-index, use one element with a gradient and a padding, then another one inside with the black background. It won't cost much and will be solid. ;)  example https://play.tailwindcss.com/ASDzzl3tju?file=css

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <div class="main">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quia ullam fugit quaerat voluptates culpa dolores id
            veritatis suscipit quo officia minus, ex totam velit praesentium explicabo, exercitationem blanditiis numquam
            doloremque?
        </div>

<style>
.main {
            background-color: black;
            max-width: 80%;
            padding: 1rem;
            position: relative;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 8px;
        }

        .main:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: -5px;
            left: -5px;
            right: -5px;
            bottom: -5px;
            width: calc(100% + 10px);
            height: calc(100% + 10px);
            z-index: -1;
            border-radius: 12px;
            background: linear-gradient(130deg, #ff7a18, #af002d 41.07%, #319197 76.05%);
        }


</style>
```

Comment: I just tried this code and it isn't working for me